# Why go-sql-driver fails to handle NULL in MySQL bigint field?

Tags: mysql, go, null, bigint

I am using [go-sql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) to connect to MySQL database. In one of my table I am using a field called queue_length as BIGINT. This field is NULL by default. When I try to query all the fields from the table using go-sql-driver in Golang, the fields after queue_length are not coming in the result set including queue_length.

In my use case,

**Table fields**
[unique_id, qid, title, text, queue_length, user_id, date_created, last_updated]

When I execute the following code I am getting values for fields before queue_length but [queue_length, user_id, date_created, last_updated] fields are not coming in result set.

But if I don't select queue_length, all fields are coming in result set. I am scanning queue_length in queueLength variable in code which is of type int64. The value coming from table is NULL. I tried type conversion also. Didn't work.

Is this a bug in go-sql-driver or am I doing anything wrong? Could anyone help me with this?

```
func GetQueues(uniqueId string) ([]*objects.Queue, error) {
    db, err := GetDBConnection()
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT qid, title, text, queue_length, user_id, date_created, last_updated FROM queue WHERE unique_id = ?", uniqueId)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var qId             string
    var title           string
    var text            string
    var userId          string
    var dateCreated     string
    var lastUpdated     string
    var queueLength     int64
    var queue           *objects.Queue
    var queues          []*objects.Queue

    for rows.Next() {
        err           = rows.Scan(&qId, &title, &text, &queueLength, &userId, &dateCreated, &lastUpdated)
        queue         = &objects.Queue{ QId: qId, Title: title, Text: text, UniqueId: uniqueId, UserId: userId, DateCreated: dateCreated, LastUpdated: lastUpdated, QueueLength: queueLength }
        queues        = append(queues, queue)
    }
    err = rows.Err()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    return queues, err
}
```

Comment: how about the err of scan? you just ignore it

Comment: Yeah I was able to find the issue once I print the error. Caleb's solution works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`queueLength` should be a [`NullInt64`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#NullInt64) instead of an `int64`.

```
var queueLength sql.NullInt64
```

In Go `int`s can't be `nil` so there's no way for `Scan` to save `NULL` in `queueLength`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool for Null and Zero fields, it includes many data types.

The github url is https://github.com/guregu/null